# DataExporter not working with column filters on dataTable in Primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, data-export

I have a custom dataTable tag, which I am using on all of my views, it's located here: src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/tags/custom_datatable.xhtml

My problem is, if I make a filtering using on one or more filterable columns and make an export using the dataExporter, the column filtering(s) get lost, so the export ignores these additional filterings. How can I change this?

This is the source for the custom datatable tag:

```
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $ = jQuery;
            var scrollPos;

            function saveScrollPos() {
                        scrollPos = $(".ui-datatable-scrollable-body").scrollTop();
            }
            function getScrollPos() {
                    $(".ui-datatable-scrollable-body").scrollTop(scrollPos);
            }
    </script>

    <p:dataTable id="#{id}" value="#{value}" var="item" widgetVar="#{widgetVar}"                 
                 draggableColumns="true" filterDelay="1000"
                 styleClass="breakwords"
                 emptyMessage="#{bundle.EmptyMessage}" filteredValue="#{controller.filteredItems}"
                 selectionMode="single" selection="#{controller.selected}"
                 rowKey="#{item.id}"
                 rowStyleClass="#{rowStyleClass}"
                 sortBy="#{sortBy}" sortOrder="#{(sortOrder!=null)?sortOrder:'ascending'}"
                 scrollRows="30" scrollable="true" liveScroll="true" scrollHeight="400"
                 tableStyle="#{tableStyle}"                 
                 >
        <p:ajax event="rowSelect"   update="createButton viewButton editButton deleteButton"/>
        <p:ajax event="rowUnselect" update="createButton viewButton editButton deleteButton"/>
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p:outputPanel >
                <p:inputText id="globalFilter" style="width:150px" onkeyup="PF('#{widgetVar}').filter()" placeholder="Searching..."/>

                <h:commandLink style="float:right">
                    <p:graphicImage name="/images/csv.png" width="24"/>
                    <p:dataExporter type="csv" target="#{id}" fileName="list"/>
                </h:commandLink>

                <h:commandLink style="float:right">
                    <p:graphicImage name="/images/excel.png" width="24"/>
                    <p:dataExporter type="xls" target="#{id}" fileName="list" />
                </h:commandLink>


                <p:commandButton icon="ui-icon-refresh" oncomplete="javascript:window.location.reload();" action="#{controller.refresh}" value="Refresh" style="float:left" />
                <p:commandButton id="toggler" type="button" value="Oszlopok" style="float:left" icon="ui-icon-calculator" />
                <p:columnToggler datasource="#{id}" trigger="toggler" >
                    <p:ajax event="toggle" listener="#{controller.getControllerDelegate().onToggle}" />
                </p:columnToggler>
            </p:outputPanel>
        </f:facet>
        <ui:insert />
    </p:dataTable>
</ui:composition>
```

My Primefaces version:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.2</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

The PrimeFaces exporter should handle this. If the backing bean values for the data table are placed in `@RequestScoped`, this can cause this particular behavior - loosing the filter values when the export is triggered. The solution is to put the backing bean values for filtering and other table properties under `@ViewScoped`.

Comment: Or the 'undervalued' Deltaspike `@Viewaccessscoped`